# Can I add multiple analyzers.cs files and code fixers files in a single solution for writing a Roslyn analyzer in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn, analyzer, codefixprovider

I am new to developing analyzers and code fixes using Roslyn Analyzer. I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. I am creating an Analyzer with code fix in Visual Studio.
Or do I need to create a separate solution for each rule (which includes Analyzer.cs and CodeFixProvider.cs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple analyzers or fixers in the same project, no problem. I think the only advice would be if the analyzers are entirely unrelated you may want to break them up, if only because people using your analyzers might want to consume one but not the other.